# javascript escape special characters except non english

Tags: javascript, escaping

I have a problem with unescaping non-english characters.

For Example,

```
var text1 = "ABC Farmacéutica Corporation".
text1 = escape(text1);

output: ABC%20Farmac%E9utica%20Corporation
```

But I would like to escape only special characters other than non-english characters like é.
Do we have any logic for these characters to be ignored?

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape function returns the text escaped in the Unicode format. Space is represented as %20 (hexadecimal). If I understand you correctly you don't want to escape é, in this case, only the space character. The only way I can see this is possible is that you have a table containing those non-english characters that you don't want to be escaped and refer to it. Something like this:

```
var dontEscape = "éöå....and_so_on";
var text = "ABC Farmacéutica Corporation";
var escaped = "";
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  var test = text.substring(i, i+1); // charAt is unsafe with unicode chars
  escaped = test.indexOf(test.toLowerCase()) == -1 ? escape(test) : test;
}
```

Is there any special reason for why you want to escape characters selectively?

Comment: or the other way round: have a table of characters that you **do** want to escape

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I just checked the logic and finally when I printed the output I am not getting the characters escaped with spacebar in between the line. Well, I need to escape those characters other than english and need to send it to Java end.

Comment: I can't put the limited characters like the one you suggested because I use more languages in future.

Comment: Instead of following the remaining rules, I am just following these rules, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters